# Swagger shows wrong id field using Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, swagger-2.0, springfox

I'm using Spring Boot + Spring DATA REST and Swagger (Springfox 2.7.0). Spring DATA REST follows HATEOAS principles, so id field should never be present in return resources.
In GET methods this works fine but in POST methods the form show an id parameter I don't understand where it comes from.

This is the screenshot of the Swagger ui. Like you see, the form contains an id parameter of type path that is not present in the model definition.

I'm sure it is not needed, in fact doing a request via Postman, it works without set id param.
Also in swagger everything works fine, filling id param with a random value.

Is it an incompatibility between Spring DATA REST and Swagger or I should set something more?
I followed instructions here:http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#support-for-spring-data-rest

[image]

=================== UPDATE ==============================

This issue is resolved in SpringFox version > 2.7.0.
Here the link to the bug: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1839

Comment: NOTE: This is a bug that has been addressed in versions greater that 2.7.0 of springfox

Comment: Thanks @Dilip Krishnan I was going to update my question.